# Error setting SSL ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssl

i have some problem here, i have .key and .crt file for the webserver that i need installed manually.

done adding this in apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf

```
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/sslcrtbppt.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/private/sslkeybppt.key
```

after that i reload the apache2 but it still not secure if i type https mydomain.org in the browser.

then checked it in digicert the result does not match with mydomain name because there are ip address not my dns :

```
Common Name = xx.xx.xx.5

Issuer = xx.xx.xx.5

Serial Number = C47861E1DDF9ECDD

SHA1 Thumbprint = F22B177C1890D1061D0CCD696F48C26DF7C6A774

Key Length = 2048

Signature algorithm = SHA256 + RSA (excellent)

Secure Renegotiation: Supported
```

so what am i missing here?
thanks for your response all.

ps: sorry for my bad english

Comment: The domain may use its own configuration snippet, with a different certificate section rather than default-ssl.conf

Answer (score 1):

Your browser is always going to throw an error if the URL doesn't match the CN in the certificate.
You'll need to re-generate your certificate with your domain name as the common name.

Comment: its wildcard certificate and it is match with my domain name

Comment: Unless the cert has SubjectAltName (SAN) extension -- I don't know if digicert would have shown this -- in which case SAN must match URL and CN is ignored. Although it is clearly selfsigned and _many_ of the tools people use to create selfsigned certs don't do SAN at least by default. @Nano: the cert in your Q is not wildcard, and if it's IP-address format as you said it _can't_ be wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

ok finally this problem solved, i just edit the wrong file,

```
SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/yoursslcrt.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/private/yoursslkey.key
```

this must configure in **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/yourdomain.conf**, and must add **SSL Chain File** also

```
SSLCertificateChainFile   /etc/ssl/yoursslca.ca-bundle
```

thanks all.